# Detecting where a tap is made in CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, cashapelayer

I'm trying to implement a custom graph that needs to react to touch. I'm drawing the graph inside of a view controllers view using a `CAShapeLayer` The code is as follows:

```
var PILL_GRAPH_ENDING_X_AXIS    : CGFloat!
    var PILL_GRAPH_BEGINNING_X_AXIS : CGFloat!
    var PILL_GRAPH_DRAW_WIDTH       : CGFloat!
    var PILL_GRAPH_Y_AXIS           : CGFloat!

    var graphLayer                  : CAShapeLayer!
    var tapGestureRecognizer        : UITapGestureRecognizer!

    //MARK: View Management
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewTapped:")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("View will appear has been called")
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        print("View will layout subviews")
        PILL_GRAPH_Y_AXIS = view.frame.size.height/2
        PILL_GRAPH_DRAW_WIDTH = 80
        PILL_GRAPH_ENDING_X_AXIS = view.frame.size.width-50
        PILL_GRAPH_BEGINNING_X_AXIS = 50
        drawPillGraph()
    }

    //MARK: Graph Drawing

    func drawPillGraph() {
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        graphLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        //Prepare the line drawing
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: PILL_GRAPH_BEGINNING_X_AXIS, y: PILL_GRAPH_Y_AXIS))
        let endingPoint = CGPoint(x: PILL_GRAPH_ENDING_X_AXIS, y: PILL_GRAPH_Y_AXIS)
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(endingPoint)
        graphLayer.opacity = 1.0
        graphLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        graphLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        graphLayer.lineWidth = PILL_GRAPH_DRAW_WIDTH
        graphLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        graphLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
        view.layer.addSublayer(graphLayer)
    }

    func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("View tapped")

        let touch = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)

    }
```

This will produce a graph that looks like this:

[image] 
   What I would like to do is be able to detect when the red graph is tapped and the tap point `CGPoint` specifically in the graph that is tapped. I've tried a few different approaches trying to use `hitTest:` and `CGPointContainsPoint` but I've been unable to successfully achieve what I'm trying to do. If anyone has an example on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: implementing a hitTest method is the correct solution. If your code isn't working, edit your question to show that code and we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I copied straight from a project of mine (except for the `CGPathContainsPoint` code). The gesture recognizer in my case was a long press, but this is how I implemented `hitTest:`

```
func didLongPressView(lpGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = lpGesture.locationInView(self)
    let point = self.convertPoint(location, fromView: nil)

    let foundLayer = self.rootLayer!.hitTest(point)

    if let shapeLayer = foundLayer as? CAShapeLayer {
        // You've found a shape layer, see if the point is inside
        // its path
        if CGPathContainsPoint(shapeLayer.path, nil, point, false) {
            // The tap was inside the shape layer's path.

        }

    }

}
```

The `rootLayer` variable is the outer most layer in my layer hierarchy (top level parent).

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 3.0**, things are a little cleaner & different.

```
    func buttonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Check location of tap in the View.
    let location = tapGesture?.location(in: self.view)
    // Convert location into a Point
    let point = self.view.convert(location!, from: nil)

    if shapeLayer!.path!.contains(point) {
        startAnimation()
    }
```

Or using your **LongPress** example Matt...

```
    func didLongPressView(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    // Check location of long press in the View.
    let location = lpGesture?.location(in: self.rootLayer)
    // Convert location into a Point
    let point = self.rootLayer.convert(location!, from: nil)

    if shapeLayer!.path!.contains(point) {
        startAnimation()
    }
```

i.e. tapGesture/lpGesture declared outside of this function and with ShapeLayer already instantiated as CAShapeLayer() in viewDidLoad (like below)....

```
    self.shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer!.path = shapeBezier.cgPath
    shapeLayer!.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer!)
```